# Netlogo move turtles in the direction of a patch stop in the middle

Tags: netlogo, move

I want my turtles to move in the direction of a random patch, but stop in the middle of the distance, and then select another random patch and again stop in the middle.

I'm having a lot of problems developing the code.

Comment: not much, I just know that with move-to it goes to a random patch:   
   to setup
 clear-all
  create-turtles  1 [
    set color white
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    ] 
end

to move
  move-to one-of patches
end

Comment: Check out the "Move Towards Target Example" in the Models Library- it should get you started.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow! You can edit your question after posting it. That's a much better way to add code to your question than putting it in a comment — very hard to read code in a comment, because it ends up all mashed onto one line.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps!

```
breed [destinations destination]
breed [people person]
globals [start dist_so_far on-going]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-people 1 [set shape "person" set color black]
  create-destinations 5
  ask destinations[set shape "flag" setxy random-xcor random-ycor]
  ask patches [set pcolor white]
end

to go
  foreach sort-on [who] destinations [?1 ->
  set on-going true  
    while [on-going][
  ask ?1 [watch-me hatch 1 [set hidden? true set start self]]  
  ifelse dist_so_far <= real_dist start
  [ask one-of people [face ?1 fd 0.5 set dist_so_far dist_so_far + 0.5]]
  [ask ?1 [die] set on-going false]
    ]
  ]
end

to-report real_dist [x]
  let dist_x abs([xcor] of x - [xcor] of one-of people) / 2
  let dist_y abs([xcor] of x - [xcor] of one-of people) / 2
  report sqrt(dist_x ^ 2 + dist_y ^ 2)
end
```